# How to rename two files - first into second and opposite

Tags: linux, shell, rename

To switch two filenames in place I can:

```
mv first firstTmp
mv second first
mv firstTmp second
```

**Is this possible with simple one-liner, and preferably without using temporal filename?**

Comment: `mv -f first firsttmp && mv -f second first && mv -f firsttemp second` (that's the only game in town... You can change it up and use `cp` and a final `rm`, but you are just doing the same thing with an additional command)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You might also use `mktemp` instead of hardcoding the "firstTmp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just think, how will it be possible without using a temporary file. If you change the name of the file to second file you are going to lose the second file forever. You can do it without a temp file but still the process is more time consuming. You have to rename and move the file to a different (say \tmp) directory and second file to the name of first file and copy the file from `\tmp` to your current directory.